# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte pySpark Kafka

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

```
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(
    ssc,
    'zookeeperserver1.sys.net:2181,zookeeperserver2.sys.net:2181,zookeeperserver3.sys.net:2181,zookeeperserver4.sys.net:2181,zookeeperserver5.sys.net:2181,zookeeperserver6.sys.net:2181',
    'spark-streaming23',
    {'topic-name':3})

lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
lines.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: In future please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your posts and use [edit] link, not comments, to add more content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like either keys or values are not UTF-8 encoded. Both `createStream` and `createDirectStream` take two additional arguments:

> - **keyDecoder** – A function used to decode key (default is utf8_decoder)
> - **valueDecoder** – A function used to decode value (default is utf8_decoder)

As you can see both default to [`utf8_decoder`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d9798c834f3fed060cfd18a8d38c398cb2efcc82/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py#L34-L38). If

- You know that one or both are not valid UTF-8 strings you can provide your own decoder or just use identity function to get raw input:

  ```
  KafkaUtils.createStream(
      ssc, ..., keyDecoder=lambda x: x, valueDecoder=lambda x: x
  )
  ```
- If you suspect that problem is in some malformed entries you can replace existing `decoder` with one, which handles decoding exceptions. Something around these lines should do the trick:

  ```
  from pyspark.streaming.kafka import utf8_decoder

  def safe_utf8_decode(s):
      try:
          return utf8_decoder(s)
      except UnicodeDecodeError:
          pass
  ```

That being said, unless your looking for more advanced applications, where `DStreams` are still irreplaceable, I'd rather recommend [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but how to replace UTF 8 with other decoding option